# An isomorphism between Tor over different rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products, derived-functors, flatness

I have an exercise which is:

> Let $k$ be a commutative ring, and $R$ is a $k$-algebra which is
>   flat as a $k$-module. Prove that if $B$ is an $R$-module (and hence a
>   $k$-module), then $$R \otimes_k \mathrm{Tor}_n^k(B,C) \simeq \mathrm{Tor}_n^R(B,R\otimes_k C)$$ for all $k$-modules $C$ and all $n \geq 0$.

I attempted the following. I took a resolution $\mathbf{P}_{\bullet}$ of $C$ as a $k$-module and tensorized with $B$, yielding
$$ \cdots \to B \otimes_k  P_n  \to \cdots  \to B \otimes_k P_1 \to B \otimes_k P_0 \to 0.$$
The homology of this becomes $\mathrm{Tor}^k_n(B,C)$. Then I tried following two roads:

1. Considering the sequence $$0 \to  Im(d_{n+1}\otimes Id) \to \ker(d_n \otimes Id) \to \mathrm{Tor}_n^k(B,C) \to 0,$$
   which is exact, and passing $R \otimes_k \square$. Since, $R$ is $k$-flat, this will yield an exact sequence. However I wasn't able to continue in this road.
2. Tensorizing $\mathbf{P}_{\bullet}$ with $R$ as a $k$-module, obtaining
   $$ \cdots \to  R \otimes_k P_n  \to \cdots \to R \otimes_k P_1 \to R \otimes_k P_0 \to 0,$$
   which are all $R$-modules, and is a resolution of $R \otimes_k C$. However, I don't know that this resolution is projective over $R$ (actually, I think this is false, since tensorizing with $B \otimes_R\square $ would make $R$ vanish). Therefore, this road got blocked as well.

I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an exact sequence of $k$-modules $0\to X\to Y\to C\to 0$, where $Y$ is projective.

Then also $R\otimes_k Y$ is projective as $R$-module, because $Y$ is a direct summand of a free $k$-module and this implies $R\otimes_k Y$ is a direct summand of a free $R$-module. Now we have the long exact sequence
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}
\dots\to\Tor_{n+1}^k(B,Y)\to\Tor_{n+1}^k(B,C)\to
\Tor_n^k(B,X)\to\Tor_n^k(B,Y)\to\Tor_n^k(B,C)\to\\
\dots\to\Tor_2^k(B,Y)\to\Tor_2^k(B,C)\to\Tor_1^k(B,X)\to
\Tor_1^k(B,Y)\to\Tor_1^k(B,C)\to \\
B\otimes_k X\to B\otimes_k Y\to B\otimes_k C\to 0
$$
For $n>0$, we essentially have
$$
\Tor_{n+1}^k(B,C)\cong \Tor_n^k(B,X)
$$
and, obviously,
$$
R\otimes_k\Tor_{n+1}^k(B,C)\cong R\otimes_k\Tor_n^k(B,X)
$$
(note that here we don't need flatness of $R$).

Similarly, we get, for $n>0$,
$$
\Tor_{n+1}^R(B,R\otimes_k C)\cong \Tor_n^R(B,R\otimes_k X)
$$
(here we use the fact that $R\otimes_k Y$ is projective).

Notice also that we have a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
R\otimes_k (B\otimes_k X) @>>> R\otimes_k (B\otimes_k Y) @>>> 
  R\otimes_k (B\otimes_k C) @>>> 0 \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
B\otimes_k (R\otimes_k X) @>>> B\otimes_k (R\otimes_k Y) @>>> 
  B\otimes_k (R\otimes_k C) @>>> 0 
\end{CD}
$$
where the vertical arrows are isomorphisms. Here we're using flatness of $R$, which is also used to build the homomorphism between the two long exact sequences.

This implies $R\otimes_k\Tor_1^k(B,C)\cong\Tor_1^k(B,R\otimes_k C)$. This starts off the standard dimension shifting argument.

Comment: Sorry, but looking back, I have a doubt. How were you able to get $\mathrm{Tor}_1^R (B, R \otimes_k C)$ from the last diagram? Since you have $\otimes_k$, shouldn't it be $\mathrm{Tor}_1^k (B, R \otimes_k C)$?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo The kernel of the first arrow in the top row is $R\otimes_k\mathrm{Tor}_1^k(B,C)$; the kernel of the first arrow in the bottom row is $\mathrm{Tor}_1^R(B,R\otimes_kC)$. The vertical isomorphisms induce a natural isomorphism between the kernels.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I understand what you said, but now it is not clear to me how the new diagram was formed since they are based on different tensorizations.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I fixed the wrong fix; I'm not so sure the result you want to prove is correct, though. Feel free to remove the tick

Comment: Thanks for the patience. Just for reference, this is an exercise of Rotman's book - An Introduction to Homological Algebra.

Comment: I think that combining my idea of $2$ together with your explanation as to why $R \otimes_k Y$ is $R$-projective, the result is at hand. I'll try to write it down.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo For $n=0$, the isomorphism would be $R\otimes_kB\otimes_kC\cong B\otimes_RR\otimes_kC\;(\cong B\otimes_kC)$, which is not true, in general.

Comment: Maybe the exercise is intended for both Tor's to be over $k$? Would it make this work?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I think so.

Answer (score 4):

(Disregard my previous answer, I misread the question.) I think your second idea is correct.

> I don't know that this resolution is projective over $R$.

Base change $R\otimes_k -$ always takes projective $k$-modules to projective $R$-modules, so this is true. ($P$ is projective over $k$ if and only if $P\oplus Q \cong k \left<X\right>$ is a free $k$-module for some $Q$; after taking base change, you see that $(R\otimes_k P) \oplus (R\otimes_k Q) \cong R \left<X\right>$ is a free $R$-module on the same set of generators.)

---

I think you had in mind something like the following argument. If $P_\bullet \twoheadrightarrow C$ is a resolution of $C$ by projective $k$-modules, then
$$\tag{*} \operatorname{Tor}^k_n (B,C) \cong H_n (B\otimes_k P_\bullet).$$
Now $R\otimes_k P_\bullet \twoheadrightarrow R\otimes_k C$ is a resolution of $R\otimes_k C$ by projective $R$-modules (it is a resolution since $R\otimes_k -$ is exact by our assumption, and $R\otimes_k P_n$ are projective, since base change preserves projectives). We have
$$\tag{**} \operatorname{Tor}_n^R (B, R\otimes_k C) \cong H_n (B\otimes_R R\otimes_k P_\bullet).$$
It remains to put together (*) and (**):
$$R\otimes_k \operatorname{Tor}^k_n (B,C) \cong R\otimes_k H_n (B\otimes_k P_\bullet) \cong H_n (R\otimes_k B\otimes_k P_\bullet) \cong H_n (B\otimes_R R\otimes_k P_\bullet) \cong \operatorname{Tor}_n^R (B, R\otimes_k C)$$
($R\otimes_k -$ is exact, hence commutes with taking homology).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't understand what happened on $H_n (R\otimes_k B\otimes_k P_\bullet) \cong H_n (B\otimes_R R\otimes_k P_\bullet)$. Why is that isomorphism valid? And another thing which is bothering me is that I don't know why $B \otimes_R R \otimes_k P_{\bullet}$ is not $B \otimes_k P_{\bullet}$.

Comment: "Why $B\otimes_R R \otimes_k P_\bullet$ is not $B\otimes_k P_\bullet$" — well, $B\otimes_R (R \otimes_k P_\bullet) \cong (B\otimes_R R)\otimes_k P_\bullet \cong B\otimes_k P_\bullet$ (isomorphism of abelian groups).

Comment: If you treat Tor's just as abelian groups, then we have simply $\operatorname{Tor}^k_n (B,C) \cong \operatorname{Tor}^R_n (B, R\otimes_k C)$.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, this problem comes from Rotman's *Introduction to Homological Algebra*, it is Exercise 6.16.  I do believe there is a (rather large) typo in it.  I believe it should read:

> Let $k$ be a commutative ring, and $R$ is a $k$-algebra which is flat as a $k$-module. Prove that if $B$ is an $R$-module (and hence a $k$-module), then
> $$\mathrm{Tor}^k_n(B,C)≃\mathrm{Tor}^R_n(B,R⊗_kC),$$  for all $k$-modules $C$ and all $n≥0.$