# Counter-example for a tensor equality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, homological-algebra

This is kind of a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035658/an-isomorphism-between-tor-over-different-rings), which I fear is wrongly stated (as pointed out by @egreg).

The question is: What is an example of a ring $k$, a ring $R$ which is a $k$-algebra and which is flat as a $k$-module, a $R$-module $B$ and a $k$-module $C$ such that

$$R \otimes_k B \otimes_k C $$
is not isomorphic to
$$B \otimes_R R \otimes_k C ?$$

Comment: Isn't $B \otimes_R R \otimes_k C$ isomorphic to $B \otimes_k C$? Did you mean to type $B \otimes_k R \otimes _k C$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes. I just stated as I did because it is what the exercise in the other question would directly imply by mere application of the case $n=0$.

Comment: Wouldn't be an example with $R \otimes_k B \not\cong B$ be enough?

Comment: @ctst Yes.${}{}$

Comment: Then $k=\mathbb Z$ and $R=B=\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ should do the trick.

Comment: @ctst Great! Thank you, it indeed does. Could you post an answer so I can accept? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for $R \otimes_k B \not\cong B \cong R \otimes_R B$ is enough.

Considering $k= \mathbb Z$ and $R=B=\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ (with pointswise multiplication/addition and obvious scalar multiplication) we get as counterexample:

$$R \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B \cong \mathbb Z^4 \not\cong \mathbb Z^2 =B \quad \text{(as } \mathbb Z \text{-modules)}$$

Since $R$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module, it is flat.